# Wait after strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script

After the strategy got stopped out (exit) I'd like to wait before I enter a new deal.

I tried to use barssince but I cannot find a condition meeting the last exit.

I expect to wait 4 hours after an exit occures before I enter a new trade.

```
//@version=3
strategy("ABC", shorttitle="ABC", initial_capital=1000, commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, commission_value = 0.075, overlay = true, linktoseries = true)
nominal = 1000/close
SL = 0.0
SLold = nz(SL[1])
SL :=  max(max(max(strategy.position_avg_price,ohlc4)-atr(10)*3, strategy.position_avg_price * 0.96), SLold)
buy = cci(close,40)<50
testPeriodStart = timestamp(2018,2,1,0,0)
if time >= testPeriodStart 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, nominal, when = buy)
    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop = SL)
plot(SL, color = #006400)
```

Comment: You can implement a counter and increment its value by one, if you exit the trade. For that, you also need to have a variable to see if you are in the trade or out of the trade. For each bar, your script will be re-executed, and you should use the history reference operator to increment the counter. If you can show some code, I can help you more. Of course, this method can only work for a specific time frame. For different time frames, you need different amount of bars to reach 4h time period.

Comment: Thank you. I will stay in the same time frame of 1h bars. testPeriodStart = timestamp(2018,2,1,0,0)
testPeriodEnd = timestamp(2019,4,30,0,0)
if time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodEnd
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, nominal, when = buy)
    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop = SL)

Comment: Please edit your question and add new information (your code) there.

Comment: sure. I did. please see my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
//@version=3
strategy("ABC", shorttitle="ABC", initial_capital=1000, commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, commission_value = 0.075, overlay = true, linktoseries = true)
nominal = 1000/close

// create a variable with time of exit
timeExit = 0.0
timeExit := nz(timeExit[1])

msToHours(timeMs) =>
    timeMs / 1000 / 60 / 60

isMoreThan4H() =>
    msToHours(time - timeExit) >= 4

// detect the exit
if strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1]
    timeExit := time

SL = 0.0
SLold = nz(SL[1])
SL :=  max(max(max(strategy.position_avg_price,ohlc4)-atr(10)*3, strategy.position_avg_price * 0.96), SLold)
buy = cci(close,40)<50
testPeriodStart = timestamp(2018,2,1,0,0)
if time >= testPeriodStart 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, nominal, when = buy and isMoreThan4H())   // Here added a check that is more than 4h since last exit
    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop = SL)


plot(SL, color = #006400)
```